# In IE 11 Angular 5 Cache Issue

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, caching, browser-cache

We are using Angular 5 and in our project we are creating/modifying the values in UI and stored in database using REST.

After Modifying the UI and once Save is clicked. the UI is NOT showing with Modified UI rather the previous one. When do a Hard Refresh in IE (ctrl + F5) then it is making the REST calls and showing the correct values. This is happening only in IE 11 and in Chrome it is working fine.

Please let me know whether we can control clearing cache only of this application from the code or any other suggestions is appreciated.

Thanks
vinod

Comment: are you using HttpClient of Http ?

Comment: I am using HttpClient

Answer (score 2):

To Solve your issue you need to override the `RequestOptions`  and  set `'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',`  like below

**custom-request-option.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseRequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class CustomRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
    headers = new Headers({
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Expires': 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT'
    });
}
```

**you.app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [
        ...
        { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: CustomRequestOptions }
    ]
})
```

Hope this Help!